# How should Biot-Savart law be used when current is uniformly distributed over a surface?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I encountered this problem and tried different methods but none lead towards an answer.

**The fact that the current is uniformly distributed over the hemispherical shell is confusing me. How should i use Biot-Savart Law in this case?**

*Any hints or explanations on what is going on here would very helpful.*[image]

Comment: You should show your work, just saying you tried different methods gives us no information on what might be causing the problem.

Comment: Imagine a plane passing through the connecting wires, let it cut the hemisphere, assume the thin area element (obtained after rotating the plane a small angle $d\theta$ ) as a semicircular wire. Calculate the magnetic field due to the thin element and then integrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the current is uniformly distributed over the shell, then the current flow in the shell in equivalent to the current flow through single infinitesimally thin wires, each bent with the radius of curvature of the shell and position at gradually increasing azimuthal angles.

Then you should think of the symmetry of the problem, and therefore which of these individual wires will cancel out the field at the centre with a "partner". The unpaired wire(s) will then give you the only net contribution.

If you don't want to use the Biot-Savart law, you can brute force this by finding the vector potential $\mathbf{A}$ and then the magnetic field $\mathbf{B} = \nabla \times \mathbf{A}$.